# what dll to load if i want to see images when deploying in runtime, also which vc dll do i realy need?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, deployment

i first time deployed my app outside of the visual studio compiler on clean pc .
and i have problem . first i dont see any images in my application
i use .png , *.gif,.ico file types i trying to add the :

```
qgif4.dll
qico4.dll
qjpeg4.dll
qjpeg4.lib
qmng4.dll
qsvg4.dll
```

the way im using my images is with *.qrc file and i was hoping it compile it as resource ( i really hope .. ) 
in the pro file i just added it like this:

```
RESOURCES += resources.qrc
```

and it looks like this:

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
         <file>images/image1.png</file>
         <file>images/icon-loading.gif</file>
         <file>images/filter.ico</file>  
         <file>images/icon_lp.png</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

but with no good i still see blank instead of images .
also do i need one of the vs run times dll’s in my application?

```
    msvcm90.dll
    msvcp90.dll
    msvcr90.dll
```

Thanks

Comment: how an where was your images used in the program? pls provide details about your program, version of VS etc

Comment: For the Microsoft runtimes you should install them properly with the correct vc 2008 redistributable package. http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5582 http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=2092

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image plugins need to be in the right location for the Qt plugin loader to find them.  Try putting them in an 'imageformats' directory next to your executable.

Answer (score 0):

- Use [depedency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to figure out which are the libraries linked to your application. This way put your application in a random directory, use the tool and you will see all missing references. these are the one you need to include.
- Can you show the line of code where you use an image?